# Try/Catch webdriver if is not present in the path

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I have the following Selenium code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "MYPATH\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get(MYURL);
```

I was wondering: if I want to use the `try/catch` Method, is there a specific exception to handle the program if `chromedriver.exe` is not found in the path?

The only exception that comes to my mind is the basic `WebDriverException` but I already use it for other purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting or getting the property will not throw an exception. It's also related to `System` not `Selenium` itself.

Using `System.setProperty` with chromedriver will set the path to chromedriver, even if it doesn't exist.

Using `System.getProperty` of a non-existing property will return null.

You can check if the property is set in multiple ways. However, if you want to check if `chromedriver.exe` exists in the provided path I would do it like this:

```
String myPath = "src/test/java";
File chromedriverFile = new File(myPath, "chromedriver.exe");
if (!chromedriverFile.exists()) {
    throw new RuntimeException(String.format("chromedriver.exe does not exist in path: %s", myPath));
}
```

We saved the path to a variable. Then, we created an instance of the `File` class. The first argument is the path and the second is a file name.
Then we check if this file exists or not. If not - throw an unchecked exception.

You can alter the code to do something else if file exists or not.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's a brilliant solution!